# Avoid passing null to constructor as param

Tags: java, android

I have an `AsyncTask` in a separate file as `DownloadImageAsyncTask`.java and I'm passing, along with `context`, an `ImageView` as an argument to the constructor. When AsyncTask enters `onPostExecute()` method it assigns the image to the `ImageView`.

Later I realized I need to use the same code to another part of my app but instead of assigning the image to an `ImageView` I need to assign it as a background image to a `FrameLayout`.

Since duplication is the root of a lot of errors in Programming how can I re-use the `AsyncTask` so it can handle both cases and avoid copy/paste code ?

I tried with a constructor like :

```
public DownloadImageAsyncTask(Context context, ImageView ivCover, FrameLayout flCover) {
    this.context = context;
    this.ivCover = ivCover;
    this.flCover = flCover;
}
```

where I set either `ImageView` or `FrameLayout` as null but that doesn't feels right to me. (since I know that we should avoid passing null as a param)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what is called an overloaded constructor inside the `DownloadImageAsyncTask` class. It is very similar to how you can have several methods with the same name that take different parameters.

```
public DownloadImageAsyncTask(Context context, ImageView ivCover) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.ivCover = ivCover;
}

public DownloadImageAsyncTask(Context context, FrameLayout flCover) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.flCover = flCover;
}
```

To check the running instance of your result variable, you can do the following, although you may want to sprinkle in some `null` checks as well

```
if(result instanceOf ImageView)
{
    // do stuff
}
else if(result instanceOf FrameLayout)
{
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks! I thought of it but then again in `onPostExecute()` how can I tell for which View (imageView or FrameLayout) I want to add the image ?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer that question

Comment: But `ivCover` will always be an instanceOf ImageView . Same goes for flCover will always be an instance of `FrameLayout` since I have already declared those two variables in AsyncTask :    ` ImageView ivCover;
    FrameLayout flCover;`

Comment: I mean ivCover and flCover are variables declared and not a result which I don;t know its type.

Comment: Edited. Simply do the conditional check on your `result` variable instead of your class level variables

Answer (score 1):

I would do with constructor override for seperate `ImageView` and `FrameLayout`. Then inside `AsyncTask` methods use `Object` as param and in `onPostExecute(Object result)` just check `if(result instanceOf ImageView)
else`